# Phalcon / MVC / Simple routing not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, routes, phalcon

I have a simple button which link to a new page /connect.

```
<a id="userMenuEditConnect" onclick="window.location.href = '{{url('connect')}}';">Connect</a>
```

I created a route :

```
$router->add(
        '/connect',
        array(
            'controller'    => 'connexion',
            'action'        => 'connect'
        )
);
```

In my ConnexionController, I added this code :

```
public function connectAction() {
    echo '<p>Simple Test </p>';
}
```

This doesn't work. When I click on my button, my browser redirectes me to /index.
Phpstorm tells me that my new function connectAction seems "unused".
In my browser, I have a **Status Code: 302 Found.**

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Phalcon but from the looks of it you might just need to create a view for that action in the view folder.

Comment: also not familiar with Phalcon, but wouldn't the `'action' => 'connect'` need to correspond to the action in your controller, which is (mistakenly) called `connectAction()` in stead of `connect()`?

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried to add a view, in my view/connexion folder, changed my function connectAction with $this->setViewName('connexion', 'mconnect'); and it doesn't work. I have the same issues.

Comment: @berend : No i need to have the "action" in the name function. Otherwise, I will get this error from Phalcon : Fatal error: Uncaught Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception: Action 'connect' was not found on handler 'connexion'.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like it's not a named route probably should use named route.

```
$router->add(
        'connect',
        array(
            'controller'    => 'connexion',
            'action'        => 'connect'
        )
)->setName('connectroute');
```

And then:

```
<a id="userMenuEditConnect" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url(['for': 'connectroute']) }}';">Connect</a>
```

Comment: It doesnt work if I add the slash, my browser try to reach url//connect and i get another different issue

Comment: I have updated my answer. 1. set name for route and 2. is removed slash from `router->add`. Let me know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the url in dependency injection

```
$di->set('url',function(){
    $url = new Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
},true);
```

What you have otherwise is correct. However, I advise against using

```
{{url('connect')}}
```

You should use instead

```
"/connect"
```

Less dependence on phalcon is better. There're so many bugs. I keep finding them. Very disappointed with the framework.